# An analog of Jordan curve theorem for various type of smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I would like to know whether the following tentative generalization of the Jordan curve theorem in higher dimensions and for smooth manifolds are true, and in case I ask for references proving them.

Let $M$ be an orientable connected smooth n-manifold ($n>1$) without boundary. Suppose $\iota: X_{n-1}\rightarrow M$ is a compact connected orientable $n-1$ dimensional submanifold. I expect the following to be true:

1. If the map induced in homology $\iota _* : H_{n-1}(X_{n-1})\rightarrow H_{n-1}(M)$ is trivial, then $M-X_{n-1}$ is the disjoint union of two connected n-manifolds $A$, $B$ such that $\partial A=\partial B= X_{n-1}$.

For this statement I essentially have a proof: since $X_{n-1}$ is trivial in homology $X_{n-1}=\partial A$, and then I can define $B=M-\overline{\partial A}$. Is this obvious that $B$ is connected or there might be some subtlety?

Furthermore let us assume $M$ to be also compact. Then I expect the converse to be also true:

2. If $M$ is compact, then $M-X_{n-1}$ is the disjoint union of n-manifolds $A$, $B$ such that $\partial A=\partial B= X_{n-1}$ if and only if $\iota _* : H_{n-1}(X_{n-1})\rightarrow H_{n-1}(M)$ is trivial.

Is this statement true? An obvious counterexample to the second statement if we drop compactness is $\mathbb{R}^2-\left\{0\right\}$.

Comment: What is the role of the subscript $d-1$ in the question? Do you mean that $X$ has dimension $n-1$? What you have for 1 is very far from a solid proof.  Also, do you mean reduced homology? Otherwise, the induced map is never zero.

Comment: This can be attacked with a sufficiently general version of Poincaré duality. It only depends on (co)homology in specific degrees. Certainly, asking for triviality in all degrees (even if we take reduced) is too much, consider e.g. $S^1\times S^1$ in  $S^2\times S^1$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan yes sorry I should have wrote $n-1$ instead of $d-1$, and I meant it is a co-dimension one submanifold. Moreover I am assuming $n>1$.

Comment: @Thorgott You are probably right, I should only ask for $\iota _* : H_{n-1}(X_{n-1}) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(M)$ to be trivial.

Comment: But consider $\mathbb{RP}^2$ in $\mathbb{RP}^3$.

Comment: In addition to considering reduced homology, you also need $X_{n-1}$ to be connected, right?

Comment: Yes you are all right. Sorry I need to add couple of assumpions, like orientability... I am going to edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I do not think you have a proof for your statement. It certainly needs a lot more argument to go from the fact that the fundamental class of $X$ is the (algebraic) boundary of a chain, which is all the hypothesis implies, to $X$ as a subset of $M$ being the (topological) boundary of some other subset $A$.
2. Let $M$ be a compact, connected $n$-dimensional manifold and $X$ a closed (hence itself compact), connected codimension $1$ submanifold. Note that $M$ and $X$  are $\mathbb{F}_2$-orientable. Then, $H^0(M-X;\mathbb{F}_2)\cong\mathbb{F}_2^{\pi_0(M-X)}$ on one hand and $H^0(M-X;\mathbb{F}_2)\cong H_n(M,X;\mathbb{F}_2)$ on the other by a sufficiently general version of Poincaré duality. This fits into the pair sequence
   $$0\rightarrow H_n(M;\mathbb{F}_2)\rightarrow H_n(M,X;\mathbb{F}_2)\rightarrow H_{n-1}(X;\mathbb{F}_2)\rightarrow H_{n-1}(M;\mathbb{F}_2).$$
   Now, $H_n(M;\mathbb{F}_2)\cong H^0(M;\mathbb{F}_2)\cong \mathbb{F}_2$ and $H_{n-1}(X;\mathbb{F}_2)\cong H^0(X;\mathbb{F}_2)\cong\mathbb{F}_2$ by two more applications of Poincaré duality. Thus, the map $H_{n-1}(X;\mathbb{F}_2)\rightarrow H_{n-1}(M;\mathbb{F}_2)$ is injective if and only if it is non-trivial if and only if $M-X$ is (path-)connected. In the other case, $M-X$ has two (path-)components.
3. If $M$ and $X$ are additionally orientable (this is famously the case if $M$ is simply connected), the above argument can be repeated verbatim with $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients instead (the example of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ in $\mathbb{RP}^3$ shows that some orientability hypothesis is necessary). There also is a cohomological version of the conclusion if one starts with $H_0$ instead of $H^0$ (the fact that triviality of the induced map on $(n-1)$-th homology and cohomology are equivalent is somewhat surprising). It should be possible to generalize this result to the non-compact case, though I haven't considered the details.
4. Lastly, let me argue that, in the case $M-X$ is disconnected, the boundary of each of its two components is $X$. Clearly, the boundary is contained in $X$. I will now assume smoothness (I suspect that's unnecessary, but the following argument is the most natural to me). Take a tubular neighborhood $U$ of $X$ in $M$, i.e. $U$ is (diffeomorphic to) the total space of the normal bundle of $X$ in $M$. It is clear that every point of $M-X$ can be connected to a point of $U-X$ by a path in $M-X$ (take a path in $M$ to some point in $U$ and observe it has to meet $U$ before meeting $X$). Thus, $M-X$ having two path-components means that $U-X$ has at least two path-components. Furthermore, $U\setminus X$ is the total space of an $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$-bundle over $X$, whose long exact sequence is
   $$\pi_1(X)\rightarrow\pi_0(\mathbb{R}^{\times})\rightarrow\pi_0(U-X)\rightarrow\pi_0(X)=\{\ast\}.$$
   It follows that $U-X$ has at most, hence exactly, two path-components. The sequence then implies trivial monodromy, so that the normal bundle (a line bundle) is trivial. Thus, $U\cong N\times\mathbb{R}$ as bundles over $N$. It follows that the closure of each component of $U\setminus N$ in $U$ contains $X$. The previous argument implies that each of these components is the intersection of a component of $M-X$ with $U$, hence their closures in $M$ respectively contain $X$, too.